# Preparing adjacency matrix - Filling missing links

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataframe of this structure:

```
A <- data.frame(A = c("B",NA,NA,NA), 
                B = c("C","D",NA,NA), 
                C = c(NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                D = c("A",NA,NA,NA))
```

Where A,B,C and D are units of my network. My problem is, is that I have a link A -> B, but not B -> A, which is just not documented in the data that I have. Also B -> D, but not D -> B for example. I want to manipulate this dataframe (or matrix rather) such that each link shows up in each column. The dataframe should then look like this:

```
B <- data.frame(A = c("B","D",NA,NA), 
                B = c("A","C","D",NA), 
                C = c("B",NA,NA,NA), 
                D = c("A","B",NA,NA))
```

In my original data, I have around 68.000 units (columns) and around 30 documented (one sided) links (rows). So my dataframe now is quite large, and I cannot check whether each link is actually documented twice (i.e. B exists in column A, but A does not exist in column B etc.). Keep in mind, it is actually possible that in some cases both links are already documented, I cannot be sure.

I hope I could present my problem clearly. I'd be glad for any useful ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your final goal to create an `igraph` graph?

Comment: yes in the end that'd be the goal.

Comment: Something like `A |> stack() |> na.omit() |> graph_from_data_frame() |> plot()`?

Comment: Ah great this is works perfectly, just what I needed, thank you so much. never worked with igraph before and the syntax, but I guess I can use the functions also as normal. Il lhave a look in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one solution in base R:

```r
B <- sapply(seq_along(A), function(i){
  name <- names(which(colSums(A == names(A)[i], na.rm = TRUE) > 0))
  A[[i]][head(which(is.na(A[i])), length(name))] <- name
  sort(A[[i]], na.last = TRUE)
})

setNames(data.frame(B), names(A))

     A    B    C    D
1    B    A    B    A
2    D    C <NA>    B
3 <NA>    D <NA> <NA>
4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `igraph`

```
library(igraph)

g <- rev(na.omit(stack(A))) %>%
   graph_from_data_frame()

B <- list2DF(
   lapply(
      setNames(ego(g, mindist = 1), names(V(g)))[names(A)],
      \(x) `length<-`(names(x), nrow(A))
   )
)
```

which gives

```
> B
     A    B    C    D
1    B    A    B    A
2    D    D <NA>    B
3 <NA>    C <NA> <NA>
4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Probably a better option, and which deals with edge cases more systematically. +1

Comment: @Maël thanks and your base R option is excellent (i usually prefer base R, you know), +1 already as well!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for both your answers. Regarding the igraph solution of @ThomasIsCoding: I tried applying your solution, unfortunately I get an error saying:

```
Error in list2DF(lapply(setNames(ego(g, mindist = 1), names(V(g)))[names(DF)],  : 
  all variables should have the same length
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)".
```

The warning says:

```
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : length of NULL cannot be changed
2: In `length<-`(names(x), nrow(DF)) : length of NULL cannot be changed
```

And so on. I don't quite understand it. After all, it is a dataframe, so the variables cant be of different length.

Comment: I figured he has an issue with empty columns so I initially turned all NA into a random string "no" and ran it again. Now it works. I get a DF B. Now I have the fact that each ID matches with "no" and NA otherwise, But I can just turn "no" into NA's again.

Comment: Ah yes. If I enter to matrix A another column E = c(NA,NA,NA,NA), and E isnt referenced in any of the other columns, I get the same error. ;)